# I got error "Type '(UITextRange) -> String?' cannot conform to 'BinaryInteger'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocol"

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift Programming and I made a simple project which will give output to a label, but I'm getting the error:

> Type '(UITextRange) -> String?' cannot conform to 'BinaryInteger'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocol.

Can anyone explain what's happening?

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblOutput: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var InputAge: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var outputAge: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func calcOutput(_ sender: Any) {
    var age = Int(InputAge.text) * 8;
    lblOutput.text = age;
}
```

Image containing the error:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2):

There are three mistakes:

1. You have to unwrap `text` of `inputAge`, this can be forced because the text property of `UITextField` is never `nil`
2. For example "ABC" cannot be converted to `Int`, therefore `Int(...)` returns an optional and you have to check if it's `nil`
3. The type of the `text` property of `UILabel` is `String`. You have to convert the result of the multiplication back to `String`

And please name functions and variables with starting lowercase letter and declare immutable *variables* as constants (`let`)

```
    @IBOutlet weak var inputAge : UITextField!
    
    @IBAction func calcOutput(_ sender: Any) {
        let stringAge = inputAge.text! 
        if let age = Int(stringAge) {
            lblOutput.text = String(age * 8)
        } else {
            lblOutput.text = "The input string is not convertible to Int"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unwrap optional of text before use:

```
@IBAction func calcOutput(_ sender: Any) {
    if let text = validatedField.text,
       let age = Int(text) {
        lblOutput.text = "\(age * 8)"
    }
}
```

Don't use *semicolons* at the lines end.

Use *let* if you don't update its values later.

Set text to text fields (not Int).

Comment: sure - Int(text) must unwrapped too. Updated my answer. Watch out how to work with optionals in Swift - it's one of the fundamentals of language, you have to understand how to use it.

Comment: okay, I'll go to fundamentals of optionals in swift first! Thankyou